# Fubini Theorem and non continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

We can find in any calculus textbook the following version of  Fubini Theorem:

Thm. If $f:[a,b]\times [c,d]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function then
we have that $f$ is Riemann integrable and
$$
\iint f \,dA=\int_a^b\int_c^df(x,y)\,dy\,dx=\int_c^d\int_a^bf(x,y)\,dx\,dy.
$$

**My question:** Is there any reasonable intuitive armument in oder  to convince one
that if $f$ is not a continuous function then Fubini theorem can fail?

Comment: Fubini's theorem applies to non continuous functions as long as they are integrable. I suspect that the continuity requirement is to ensure that $\int \int |f| dA$ is finite, which is a requirement for the theorem to hold.

Comment: Yes, I agree that in this particular case you can use that the closed interval is compact and a continuous functions reach its max and min. The interval has finite volume.

Answer (score 0):

Under certain general conditions Fubini's theorem is true for something called measurable functions (I don't know if you know this theory, possibly yes).

Look at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

This theorem holds without continuity.

Comment: But in this case the  lebegue integral is considered instead the riemman integral

Comment: To define the Riemann integral you just need the function to be bounded.